# Eigenvalues of special block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Suppose we have a $2n\times 2n$ matrix:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B&-A\end{bmatrix},$$ where $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$  self-adjoint matrices:
$$A^* =A \;,\quad B^* =B$$
We know that the eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of $M$ exists in pairs:
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B&-A\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2 \end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2 \end{bmatrix}. $$
Multipying by $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ from the left, and inserting $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ leads to:
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B&-A\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-c_2\\c_1 \end{bmatrix}=-\lambda\begin{bmatrix}-c_2\\c_1  \end{bmatrix}. $$
Is there a way to get the eigenvalues of $M$ ?

Comment: Have you tried computing the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: I think $M$ is a hermitian matrix so all the eigenvalues will be real

Answer (score 1):

Let $J:=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -I \\ I & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $J^{-1}=J^T=-J$ and $J^2=I$. It is easy to see that
$$J^{-1}MJ=-M$$
This means $M$ and $-M$ are similar. So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, it must also be an eigenvalue of $-M$. Also, $-\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue of $-M$ and vice versa. This means the eigenvalues of $M$ are symmetric across imaginary axis. Also, since $M$ is Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real.